# Vulkan is not working

Tags: drivers, vulkan

When I run vulkaninfo in terminal I get this:

```
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.70

ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
/build/vulkan-UL09PJ/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:2700: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

I have R9 280x graphics card and following packages installed through Synaptic Package Manager:

```
libvulkan1, libvulkan1:i386, mesa-vulkan-drivers,       mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386, vulkan-utils
```

I have no idea what is the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try running as root and see if the problem persists? `sudo vulkaninfo`

Comment: I tried with sudo and same message comes again:(

Comment: I think it's something to do with it loading the wrong libraries... I'm trying to hunt it down myself.